is TB test required for UK expats who were in UK for more than 1 year
I along with my family came to UK under Skilled worker visa in 2023. As part of initial Visa process we had taken the TB tests back in India. However, my kids (9Y and 1Y) were less than 10 years old and had never undergone this X-ray test back in India. We have been in UK along with family since then and never travelled back to India. However, today received a call claiming to be from the Health Care and asking to get the TB tests (blood test for adults and some sort of skin test for kids) done for all of us again. As per them its something needs to be done after 1 year, even though they said its not yearly ordeal.
For some reasons it feels bit odd on why this is required (even though these were submitted as part of initial Visa Approval process) after coming and being here for 1 year and no travel records and also nothing of this sort in the UK GOV website.
Is this valid or some fake calls?

The titel is a bit misleading due to the incorrect usage of the word expat. The OP is an Indian expat living in the UK. 'Is a TB test required from 3rd country nationals who are in the UK for more than 1 year' might be better.

Who is ‘the Healthcare’? If you’ve not already done so, I would check the contact number is valid and ask them to provide you with evidence (eg the relevant Immigration Rule) that this is in fact a requirement
